# AWS Simple Scaling - Will it scale in back automatically after scale out?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-auto-scaling

We are using AWS Simple Scaling policy to scale out our EC2 instance. My company will not consider other AWS scaling method ATM.

```
 Add 2 capacity units when CPUUtilization >= 70 for 5 consecutive periods of 60 seconds for the metric dimensions
```

So, we will scale out 2 units when CPU > 70%.

Here are my questions ?

1. Will EC2 scale in back to desired no of EC2 instance AUTOMATICALLY when CPI Utilisation drop less than 70% ?
2. Do I need a separate scale in policy ? If yes, what is the best CPU value ? < 60% ?
3. What is the best practise for using Simple Scaling ?

Also, one of previous workmate implemented an additional scale-in rule like this: Will that working for scale-in ? It seem strange for scale in rule with CPU greater than 15%

```
Remove 1 capacity units CPUUtilization > 15 for 12 consecutive periods of 60 seconds for the metric dimensions:
```

Comment: How did it go? The issue is still unclear?

Answer (score 1):

> Will EC2 scale in back when CPI Utilisation drop less than 70% ?

No, it will not.

> Do I need a separate simple scale in policy ? If yes, what is the best CPU value ? < 60% ?

Yes, you need a separate policy. Whether 60% is suited or not, is use-case specific.

> What is the best practice for using Simple Scaling ?

I would say stress load your application and monitor how the ASG scales with your policies and thresholds.